# Curvature length and Newton's constant in AdS

Tags: physical-constants, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

What is the dimensions of Newtons gravitational constant in arbitrary dimensions in terms of teh curvature radius?

I am looking at entanglement entropy which goes as $S \sim \frac{ l_4^2}{G_4}$. This suggests that $G_4$ has dimensions of length square. But I really struggle to find a resource where this is addressed explicitly.